# Evaluating for sequence of coefficients from the binomial theorem after using roots of unity filter

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> $$ \sum_r \binom{32}{6r}$$

My attempt: $f(x) = (1+x)^{32}$ and then I used roots of unity filter,

$$ \sum_r \binom{32}{6r} =\frac{ (1+ 1)^{32} +(1+\omega)^{32} + (1+\omega^2)^{32}+ (1+\omega^3)^{32} + (1+\omega^4)^{32} + (1+\omega^5)^{32}}{6}$$

Where $\omega$ is sixth root of unity.

Problem: It seems very difficult to actually evaluate this mess, is there any trick one could use?

Source: Algebra, Mathematics For JEE Advanced, G Tewani, Cengage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ S=\frac{ (1+ 1)^{32} +(1+\omega)^{32} + (1+\omega^2)^{32}+ (1+\omega^3)^{32} + (1+\omega^4)^{32} + (1+\omega^5)^{32}}{6}$$

What makes this sum easy to compute is the fact that the sixth roots of unity have a "nice" form:

$$
1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i, \frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i,-1, \frac{-1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} i
$$

Hint 1: Take $\sqrt3$ out after adding $1$ to required values

Hint 2: Apply De Moivres theorem

Comment: That is actually genius . Very good.